# How to add JNI sources to my project in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, java-native-interface

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3 and I have a nice jniLibs directory created by AS when importing Eclipse project. It took the jar file with .so files and it created a nice structure for every architecture:

[image: jniLibs tree]

I, however, have sources of those libraries and I would like to add them to the structure, so I could edit them and debug easily.
How should I proceed?
The only relevant entry I have in my `build.gradle` file is:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/sdk.jar')
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by removing the `dependencies` section and adding:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs {
            srcDirs = ['jni/db', 'jni/minizip', 'jni/roxml']
        }

    }
}
```

Now I can nicely track my source code in Android Studio.